# When the union probability of two random variables becomes equal to one? Is it only when one of them is certain?

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Let's say I have the two events $X_1 < T_1$ and $X_2 >T_2$,
Where $X_1,X_2$ are two dependent Gaussian variables, and $T_1,T_2>0$.

I want to know when the union probability of the two events becomes equal to one, if for example we have a predetermined value for $T_2<+\infty$.

$P(X_1 < T_1 \cup X_2 >T_2)=1$

Is it necessary that the first event $X_1<T_1$ should become certain "$T_1=+\infty$"? Or is there a smaller value for $T_1$ under which their union becomes unity?

Please advise

Comment: If $(X_1,X_2)$ has a PDF then it will be one that is positive everywhere, so that for finite $t_1,t_2$ sets like  $[t_1,\infty)\cap(-\infty,t_2]$ have positive probability. So the equality mentioned in your question can only occur if there is no PDF. E.g. if $X_1=X_2$ a.s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Examine the complement.$$\mathsf P(X_1<T_1 \cup X_2>T_2) = 1-\mathsf P(X_1\ge T_1 \cap X_2\le T_2)$$

Comment: Then it is only when one of the events at least is certain.
@Graham